# ERROR: read_util:read_line_to_codes/2: <stream> does not exist

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

While I am trying to read file and make some processing on the input and write them in another file, I met this error,

```
ERROR: read_util:read_line_to_codes/2: <stream> Number does not exist
```

Where Number is number of stream (ex: 04068B20)) and it's changed each time .

```
read_File(Stream,[H|T],LineNumber):-
    read_line_to_codes(Stream, H),      
    (H \= end_of_file -> /*open other file and write in it*/).
```

Comment: It isn't a normal error, I am using ! where there is a menu :

`code`
action(1):-!,make some processing,fail.
action(2):-!,make some processing,fail.
.....
`code`
once the user selects action(1), while backtracking it backs and fail
so it isn't a normal error while reading the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stream doesn't exist.  Could you somehow be closing the stream and/or moving/deleting the file?